Getting Clicky Web Analytics to Run on Jekyll Site
My Github Pages site uses Jekyll, and needs a web analytics tool. Clicky is one of the few that was free. The tracking code they provide to put within the <html> tag wasn't working.
<script async data-id="12345678" src="//static.getclicky.com/js"></script>
Github Pages has some constraints with JavaScript that I don't quite understand, but this gem seems simple enough. Running $ gem install jekyll-clicky says the gem is installed, and "Jekyll-Clicky" shows up when I run gem list.
The second step is to add this to the config.yml file and fill it out, though I'm not entirely sure what goes in the first line.
jekyll_clicky:              #Add this if you want to track with Clicky analytics
  site: 
    id:         # Required - replace with your tracking id

I'm clicking around my site using my phone and browser (tracking/ad blockers off), but nothing is showing up on the Clicky dashboard. How would you troubleshoot this? Does it even work?
What I tried: Nullifying the tracking code in the header with <!-- -->. Putting my site id and website name in the jekyll_clicky: field of the part that goes in the config.yml file.

Or, if anyone knows a free, non-Google alternative! Though this thread seems to suggest that neither Clicky nor any other web analytics will work with Github Pages.

Github Pages does not provide server-side analytics. However, you should be able to include client-side analytics like Clicky, usefathom.com, plausible.io etc. without any issues. Check your browsers developer tools to see whether there are any errors in the console and whether it's making network requests.

The Actions tab of the Github dashboard shows the builds weren't deploying. By removing "foobar.com" from jekyll-clicky: and site: the builds deployed again.
It now seems obvious that jekyll-clicky: is more like a header and not a field, and site: is apparently not the name of your site.
jekyll_clicky:              #Don't add anything here
  site:                     #Not sure, but not required
    id: 12345678        

